# Calling a method from another file AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, class, oop

I'm trying to create a unit test and I'm having some errors when I try to use a function from another file. You can see an example of the basic idea of what I am trying to do below. I am a beginner in Python so I'm not sure what's the problem.

In file 1: model.py

```
Class Model(parameters):

      def calc_maximum(self, data, thresholds): 
          df['Max']= ...
          return df

      def calc_model_output(self,data,param,param2): 
          S=self.calc_maximum(data,thresholds)
          Si=S+param2
          return Si
```

in file 2: test.py

```
import model as ml
import unittest 
...
...

class Tests(unittest.Testcase):
      def test_calc_maximum(self):
          Expected1=ml.Model.calc_maximum(self,input1, input2)
      def test_calc_model_output(self): 
          Expected2=ml.Model.calc_model_output(self,input1,input2,input3)
```

when I try to run test.py file, the test for `Expected1`seems to work ok, but I get the following error from the`Expected2`row:
`AttributeError: 'Tests' object has no attribute 'calc_maximum`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `self` is an instance of the test case, not an instance of `Model.` You should *create* an instance of `Model` before trying to call any of its methods.

Comment: Neither of your tests make any assertions about the result of the methods being called, so they aren't really *working*, only avoiding any explicit errors.

Comment: (`calc_maximum`, in particular, doesn't seem to *use* its `self` argument, so it doesn't really matter what you pass to it, and it calls into question whether it should be an instance method at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add brackets after Model in Expected1, i.e. make Expected1

```
Expected1=ml.Model().calc_maximum(input1,input2)
```

Do the same for Expected2

Comment: At the very least, you need to remove `self` from the call as well.

Comment: Why is that? I am assuming that self has some importance in the code, albeit I cannot see any right now

Comment: No, because `self` in the call is the instance of `Tests`, not anything that `Model` methods should care about. The only reason that didn't produce an error immediately in the OP's original code is because, calling the instance methods from the class itself, no implicit `Model` instance was passed to the method call.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, edited and thanks for reminding me